# What versions of EcmaScript does NodeJs 8 supports? Can I use polyfill to enforce compatibility in Nodejs8 for latest Ecma standard?

Tags: node.js, ecma

I was hosting my express api using firebase cloud functions and found out that the free version supports nodejs8 only.I searched for whether i could use features of ES7 / ES6 in nodejs could not find a good answer.I know that tools like babel can convert ES6/ES7 to older specification like ES5.
However, i'm not sure whether that helps when the engine does not support specifications like ES7 or ES6 and latest.

Answer (score 1):

[node-green](https://node.green/) - Check Node.js ECMAScript compatibility programmatically

Answer (score -1):

I was hosting a graphql website using mongodb as database. I found that nodejs8 does not support srv strings uri to connect to mongodb database.Also, there was workaround for that using non-srv uri. However, i did not notice that firebase did not allow for requests to uri's out of firebase.So,I could not establish a connection to mongodb.
That came out to be my problem .